# Deleted the modulo directories node, nodejs

Tags: json, linux, ubuntu, npm, npm-install

```
which node
```

> node not foun

```
nodejs server
```

> nodejs: command not found

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

> Reading package lists... Done

> Building dependency tree
> Reading status information... Done

> nodejs is already the latest version (17.2.0-deb-1nodesource1).
> 0 packages updated, 0 new packages installed, 0 to be removed and 0 not updated.

Comment: Uninstall nodejs and try reinstalling freshly

Comment: The default command is `sudo apt install --reinstall nodejs`